# What is known about minimal sets of axioms?

Tags: mathematics, axioms

There are several axioms that are known to be independent of the usual ones; for instance, the [Axiom of Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice). This axiom can be stated in several equivalent ways, e.g.:

- For every set $A$, $\mathcal{P}(A) \setminus \{\emptyset\}$ has a choice function.
- For every infinite set $A$, there is a bijective map between the sets $A$ and $A \times A$.
- Every surjective function has a right inverse.
- All sets have a cardinality, which has a strict total order.

There are several different fundamental axioms you can pick for a proof system. No matter what you pick, if your selection is powerful enough to be *useful*, you can derive the "axioms" that a different proof system uses from your axioms.

Given how axioms can be defined in terms of each other, and some sets of axioms are independent of others, it feels like you can describe the relationships between axioms using the language of graph theory, and from there you could explore minimal independent sets of axioms. I imagine there are certain properties that all sets of axioms share; I might have found one or two, but I have no idea how to go about investigating further.

I imagine somebody's already studied this, but I have no idea what they might have called it. What is known about this already?

Comment: Are you looking for [reverse mathematics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics)?

Comment: They're doing it completely differently to how I thought they would, but yes, that looks like what I'm talking about.

Comment: I'm voting to close since this does not pertain PAs, but it is a (valid) mathematical logic question, more suitable for MO or math.SE

Comment: As an argument that this should be on-topic, the question _is_ relevant to designing small kernels and axiomatic systems, and doesn't really have many other applications outside of that.

Comment: @JoshChen I've read that Wikipedia article more closely, and that might not be what I'm talking about. Reverse mathematics seems to start with systems and work out their properties; what I'm talking about is the study of systems' axioms themselves, what alternate formulations are equivalent, etc..

Comment: I think it is indeed covered by proof theory, model theory and reverse mathematics.

Comment: IMHO for PAs the more interesting question would be about optimal, in some well-defined way, sets of axioms.

Comment: I think this question could be made on topic for this site by asking, for example, what tools are a available in various proof assistants to keep track of axioms used in a proof, or visualize dependencies?

Comment: @GuyCoder Although I maintain that this question is off-topic as it stands, it is a good question and I was perhaps hasty in voting to close. Maybe a better strategy would be to not close well-asked off-topic questions until they become an issue.

Comment: The question could be reopened if it explained *why* having small sets of axioms is supposed to be good for proof assistants. Is it really? Even better would be something along the lines: in logic minimal systems of axioms are valued because they easy meta-logical analysis of a theory, how important is minimality/independence of axioms for proof assistants? As the question stands, it's just about logic and nothing else.

Comment: @GuyCoder I've been away from my computer for the past few hours. :-) I'll see about improving the question.

Comment: @AndrejBauer My only justification is “I'm making a proof assistanty thing, and knowing the answer to this question will help”. (If you have a better one, feel free to [edit].) Though that other question you suggested does seem good; do you want to [ask it](/questions/ask), or shall I?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik I tried asking a question like that, but it's hard to actually define optimal; it got closed and downvoted very quickly. Either you get something mathematically interesting but functionally useless, or your criteria are too vague. (Or you already know what you're looking for, and don't need to ask the question.)

Answer (score 7):

From the point of view of the proof assistants, Metamath is an interesting tool for studying minimal sets of axioms.

In the `set.mm` database, classical propositional calculus is [developed from the 4 axioms of Łukasiewicz](http://us2.metamath.org:88/mpeuni/mmtheorems1.html#mm5s), and then, [several other equivalent axiomatizations](http://us2.metamath.org:88/mpeuni/mmtheorems16.html#mm1560b) are presented, as well as derivations between them.

Using a Metamath function which lists the axioms from which a theorem has been proved, it is possible to show that such derivations are only based on a given set of axioms. This is also interesting if one wants to find out whether [the axiom of choice](http://us2.metamath.org:88/mpeuni/ax-ac.html) is required for a given proof.

One might also consider the intuitionistic logic: in [`iset.mm`](http://us2.metamath.org:88/ileuni/mmil.html) set theory is developed without the law of excluded middle; yet another axiomatisation.

Comment: Maybe also of interest, a recent article of Benoît Jubin proving the independence of some finite axiom-schematization of classical first-order logic: [https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.10383](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.10383)

Answer (score 2):

For set theory, I refer you to mathoverflow, there is a [similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194486/is-there-a-compendium-of-the-consistency-strength-between-the-most-important-for).

For reverse mathematics, I point you to [Reverse Mathematics Zoo](https://rmzoo.math.uconn.edu).

Comment: I'm downvoting because I want to discourage the answering of off-topic questions. If there is any way to put something about PAs in the answer, that would be and improvement

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf You can see Reverse Mathematics Zoo as a proof assistant.

Comment: Is it? I'm checking the _Usage_ page and it doesn't look like a “general purpose” PA, but perhaps it is just that the docs are incomplete or I fail to understand that they are describing that.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Oh no, RM Zoo is not general purpose, however it is still a proof assistant (*sui generis* and *sensu lato*).

Comment: I'll will reconsider if the question is kept open!